# Are there results of parabolic regularity in Heisenberg groups?

Tags: reference-request, parabolic-pde, heisenberg-groups

The $(2N +1)-$dimensional Heisenberg group $\mathbb{H}^N$ is the space $\mathbb{R}^{2N+1} = \left\{ (x,y, \tau )   \right\}\in \mathbb{R}^N \times \mathbb{R}^N \times \mathbb{R}$ equipped with the group operation

\begin{equation}
    (x,y, \tau ) \circ (\tilde{x}, \tilde{y}, \tilde{ \tau } ) = (x+ \tilde{x}, y+\tilde{y}, \tau +\tilde{ \tau } + 2  \left( x \cdot \tilde{y} - \tilde{x} \cdot y\right))
\end{equation}

where $\cdot$ denotes the standard scalar product in $\mathbb{R}^N$. The identity element for $\mathbb{H}^N$ is $0$ and $\eta^{-1} = -\eta$ for any $\eta \in \mathbb{H}^N$. The sub-Laplacian on $\mathbb{H}^N$ is defined as
\begin{equation}
    \Delta_{\mathbb{H}} = \sum_{i=1}^{N} \left( X_i \circ X_i + Y_i \circ Y_i\right),
\end{equation}
where for $i=1, \cdots, N$, $X_i$, $Y_i$ are vector fields as follows
\begin{equation}
    X_i = \partial_{x_i} - 2y_i \partial_{ \tau  } , \quad Y_i = \partial_{y_i} - 2x_i \partial_{ \tau  }
\end{equation}
Many authors have studied the problem
$$ u_t - \Delta_{\mathbb{H}} u = u^p  $$
through the operator
\begin{equation}
Fu(t)= e^{ t\Delta_{\mathbb{H}} }u_0 + \int_{0}^{t} e^{(t-s)\Delta_{\mathbb{H}}}| \cdot |_{\mathbb{H}}^{-\gamma} |u(s)|^p ds.
\end{equation}
For example, in [enter link description here](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/272398/1-s2.0-S0022039621X00332/1-s2.0-S0022039621006835/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEFMaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIDj3Mt8HQ27PIfBx%2BxOA%2FTRLThx%2F6njyI6gRR27SoXCdAiEAwiwc%2FqLMIVBPJ212ZzFDCnqg2tZ8tdfDP9xkPwYlHO8qvAUI2%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FARAFGgwwNTkwMDM1NDY4NjUiDGA1EOidtQTa%2FClUXiqQBRYuJasxtXB4OHnu0LCHyfYLN7e73BkcGWv3DaFQ3NWFEa1q65s7T7lKCkhGS1%2B5QKuF0y%2FxVK8VQlwTNkcKOqTngHz0N9jQr214FaJUqzgh4V95XmTiwpqcEIs3VaDMkXzMKtvk%2B7mixUCmcJqpWyckS9eKoOOgIt84YOqm%2Bmr%2BnQsXBm7DGgfMPoIxq5L2scem80akTAXeOEquJwxHfjUEgQeVoVErWIl0p1pPExgL9sCoyjzTl6rzs4NpTWq4vOzrh73m7CKtR4Rj1xiPtTfVOAQqsAgSj24jAw%2FisjfVwRveEoiUypqls0CGT8Tq%2B5HBhqE%2BHtFlBCWNwZwMlaM8BIzH2pzU%2FSrBjbqs%2BCZ85CHS2fn2oJQY40y7sO28pIVp6viUN1Vg2Qx7EVOjqlT4AtaprkIBE1O0tDWSGCe0E8bZpySSsyMryLY82lPw2d7KG5eqtyoGkfI4RzZdUT1js4PNu8jIBx6J0GG3w1ZqYzAbjbeNLbNvbo000uVtBN5xPBdamWFkVe5GkLy3dHXa13hUBQvXadzVJCJwwjwC4bq3l5qK%2FN5OILcoEVHsD%2BnhfBQcXo0Vh8R1IXsV%2FiRMCvW9hhirEa7CpYEGzvRRsDk5EkxP4wUHiDJeW%2BIiOOsylXnuD3vj3zYzXTR%2FehZRjVZy0Doan8P8EK1rlp4%2FxyQ6sAvhc6E72HyKBYZDOhIiH2VmnWPeDpo%2B48m4r64CGSn1u3natjVI1VCz%2F5VAUw1ZIPIYzNMDDA7u3yNNQIKsZqtoPA5DsX8vEOhgCvXzPZSXJrqVWQi26zT2HFY%2FZs%2BpbDKWkJ%2BBEYWdGBid9WM6ljnlpopNrIdBTzV5svTeYZaVyc8oZkPPaW9YTxBtMMu28KUGOrEBFghBFwsIZ5Xvoft9Mm3kBG53qyRQSXVRCc2UP5MiTuLxYX3kZnk%2F99TL5c6HMAsNETUB7vIsZ7MUHW1LZSoPIL1OGgXyRj5rirROWudjEh7s%2FX6jHfvjfvVQztYf%2BoEK%2FghtyGxtcVv%2BDKT3hy2ojSBRfKHAjkazfrx1FpDBCaZ49edTx4TM8%2FqAqXkoOqSJEUb7k52coy%2Ff7sbUmdeD5adYKCga5y%2B2tf3efsbidGSo&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20230722T190923Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTY4BFQTVKE%2F20230722%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=1f0f386f1ad4c085607283204b3ac6d285a1422ee4d69ef47bf0f5db9deab89a&hash=b3fbf34b652fcaa5cc65dfd3e92bf1ac5b679a31c67f9b916954ea74eb6dcc27&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S0022039621006835&tid=spdf-487882ee-cc55-43dc-b156-d2ccc848836f&sid=ab0d1b672dbf554c394bfd78d33c2293d118gxrqa&type=client&tsoh=d3d3LnNjaWVuY2VkaXJlY3QuY29t&ua=041459030f07020e5702&rr=7eadfa4a4c932555&cc=br), the authors showed the existence of a global solution in unimodular Lie groups. Throughout the paper it was mentioned that the solution was classic, and it was obtained through the operator above. I wonder if the author used any parabolic regularity results. More specifically, if such parabolic regularity results exist in Heisenberg groups, are they like $\mathbb{R}^N$? Can you quote me some reference where I can find such results?